# Using Prepared Statements to set Table Name

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to use prepared statements to set a table name to select data from, but I keep getting an error when I execute the query.

The error and sample code is displayed below.

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Parameter 'Pa_RaM000' specified where a table name is required.



private String query1 = "SELECT plantID, edrman, plant, vaxnode FROM [?]"; //?=date
public Execute(String reportDate){
    try {

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Display.DB_MERC);
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
        st.setString(1, reportDate);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: Yes, input sanitization in order to prevent SQL injections!

Comment: If you need to substitute different table names into a query with the same structure it points to a flaw in your database design.  At the least it points to multiple tables with the same relation attributes.  Normalise it into a single table with a "subject" column.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A table name can't be used as a parameter. It must be hard coded. So you can do something like:

```
private String query1 = "SELECT plantID, edrman, plant, vaxnode FROM [" + reportDate + "?]";
```

Comment: Ok thanks, guess ill just use a string replacement

Accepted your response as answer

Thanks!

Comment: Dont! This is a secuiry issue due to SQL-injection.

Comment: use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql` on the table name to make sure you're not putting your schema at risk.

Comment: @everyone suggesting the string-concatenation of the tablename: DONT do it. This give way to SQL-injections - the No 1 attack in OWASPs Top 10 (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)

Comment: It goes without saying that if you are going to do this then the tablename must be whitelisted (and you should use the value from the whitelist not the entered value, just to be sure; regexes etc)

Comment: Do not use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql`. It was deprecated in commons.lang3, and in any case only replaces single-quotes with double single-quotes. It does not prevent SQL injection. See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html and http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql%28java.lang.String%29.

Comment: @Benvorth easy for you to say without providing solution. We wouldn't be here if DBs supported parameterizing table names in a prepared statement. But they don't. So what is left for us to do?

Answer (score 4):

## You can't set table name in prepared statement

As said before, it is not possible to set the table name in a prepared statement with <strike>`preparedStatement.setString(1, tableName)`</strike>. And it is also not possible to add parts of the SQL query to a prepared statement (eg <strike>`preparedStatement.addSql(" or xyz is null")`</strike>).

## How to do it right without risking SQL injections?

The table name must be inserted into the SQL (or JQL) query you want to execute with string operations like `"select * from " + tableName` or `String.format("select * from %s", tableName)`

#### But how to avoid SQL injections?

If the table name does **not come from user input**, you are probably *safe*.
For example, if you make a decision like here

```
String tableName;
if(condition) {
    tableName = "animal";
} else {
    tableName = "plant";
}
final String sqlQuery = "delete from " + tableName;
...
```

If the table name **depends on the users input**, you need to *check* the input manually.
For example, with a **white-list** containing all valid table names:

```
if(!tableNamesWhitelist.contains(tableName)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(tableName + " is not a valid table name");
}
String sqlQuery = "delete from " + tableName;
```

or with an **enum**:

```
public enum Table {
    ANIMAL("animal"),
    PLANT("plant");

    private sqlTableName;
    private TableName(String sqlTableName) {
        this.sqlTableName= sqlTableName;
    }
    public getSqlTableName() {
        return sqlTableName;
    }
}
```

and then convert the user-input string like `ANIMAL` into `Table.ANIMAL`. An exception is thrown, if no fitting enumeration value does exist.

eg

```
@DeleteMapping("/{table}")
public String deleteByEnum(@PathVariable("table") Table table) {
    final String sqlQuery = "delete from " + table.getSqlTableName();
    ...
}
```

Of course these examples work with select, update, ... too and a lot of other implementations to check the user input are possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically possible with a workaround, but very bad practice.

```
String sql = "IF ? = 99\n";
sql += "SELECT * FROM first_table\n";
sql += "ELSE\n";
sql += "SELECT * FROM second_table";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

And then when you want to select from first_table you set the parameter with

```
ps.setInt(1, 99);
```

Or if not, you set it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

As a number of people have said, you can't use a statement parameter for a table name, only for variables as part of the condition.

Based on the fact you have a variable table name with (at least) two table names, perhaps it would be best to create a method which takes the entity you are storing and returns a prepared statement.

```
PreparedStatement p = createStatement(table);
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
public ResultSet getSomething(String tableName) {

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from \`"+tableName+"\`");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure you can use a PreparedStatement to specify the name of the table, just the value of some fields. Anyway, you could try the same query but, without the brackets:

```
"SELECT plantID, edrman, plant, vaxnode FROM ?"
```

Comment: You need brackets to escape "/" in queries...or it might be be for dates.  I looked it up last summer

Answer (score -3):

```
String table="pass"; 

String st="select * from " + table + " ";

PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(st);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to your answer, that way future readers can learn how to apply it to their issues and not just in this situation.

Comment: Vulnerable to SQL injection.  Do NOT do this!