# Using parameter in select statement

Tags: sql, prepared-statement

I was trying to parameterize value in Preparedstatement as below like

```
PreparedStatement ps = Connection.prepareStatement("select col_a,? from TABLE_A");
ps.setString(1,"myValue");
ps.execute();
```

I want the following return

```
COL_A    myValue
-----------------
val1     myValue
val2     myValue
```

which is comparable to a plain sql as below.

```
select col_a,'myValue' 
from TABLE_A
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable column names using prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135973/variable-column-names-using-prepared-statements)

Comment: What are you actually getting?  Just errors?

Comment: Hi folks thank you for your response... I was initially getting errors but somehow in DB2, it does work. I have no idea why and how but it does...

Answer (score 2):

You can't parametrize column names.

For dynamic column names you will need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), which can open you up to SQL injection.