# writing sql with substr data in rows

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this table in database which called `data`
[image: table data]

and i want make this sql

```
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT $menucompare,( substr($menucompare, 13, 2)) AS dayname FROM data WHERE ... ");
```

Obs

```
    $menucompare // is variable which the date is selected from table(date or date2 or date3..)
```

lets say we have this date from table `04/10/2012-(Tuesday)` under the week `6` in `w_date`, so after substracting as it saids in sql it will be `Tu` .

in week 7 there is 2 dates one .
what i want is to output by every week the days names ordered by days

exemple like that

```
  week 7

   Tu
   Fr
   .
   .
```

or

```
week 6
Tu
.
.
```

can this happen ?is there a special `WHERE` clause here ?
and is it possible to write sql where claculating how many dates are in the week 
for exemple how many dates in week 7 , in the table up there is 2 in week 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked a couple of different questions here, but before I try to address them directly it might be worth considering (if at all possible) changing the data type of your `date` columns to the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) type and then using functions such as [`` DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%a") ``](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to obtain the first characters of the relevant day name.

Also, please be very careful to avoid malicious SQL injection when inserting variables from another language into a SQL statement: consider using [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).  Sadly, to do so in this case you will stumble upon another problem because of your database design: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135973/variable-column-names-using-prepared-statements) for more information.

On to your questions:

1. > can this [the example output shown] happen?

   Yes, it can.  You want to "group" your results, so have a look at the `GROUP BY` clause to the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) statement. Try a command like:

   ```
   SELECT
     `w_date`,
     GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTR(`date`, 13, 2) SEPARATOR "\n") AS `daynames`
   FROM `data`
   WHERE ...
   GROUP BY `w_date`;
   ```

   As you can see, the results are grouped in the way you want - but the list of day abbreviations is a separate result column to the week number; to output the data precisely as shown is a further manipulation that must occur at the application level.
2. > is it possible to write sql where claculating how many dates are in the week for exemple how many dates in week 7

   Yes, absolutely.  To obtain the total number of records for a given week:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `data` WHERE `w_date` = 7;
   ```

   Or for the number of *distinct* days within a given week:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `date`) FROM `data` WHERE `w_date` = 7;
   ```

   Or to get such for every week:

   ```
   SELECT `w_date`, COUNT(*) FROM `data` GROUP BY `w_date`;
   ```

Comment: thx very clear from your side just want thing i will be glad if you can clear it to me , is to avoid sql vulnerability injection, im not good in this . you mean i better avoid to make variables in sql ?

Comment: @user1291295: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain