# What is the difference between single ( ? ) and double question mark ( ?? ) in node-mysql?

Tags: node-mysql

Am sure this is fairly obvious, to me it would make more sense if the second double question mark in the example was a single one.

**From their [docs](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql):**

Alternatively, you can use ?? characters as placeholders for identifiers you would like to have escaped like this:

```
var userId = 1;
var columns = ['username', 'email'];
var query = connection.query('SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE id = ?', [columns, 'users', userId], function(err, results) {
  // ...
});

console.log(query.sql); // SELECT `username`, `email` FROM `users` WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: I don't know node-mysql, but looking at your example statement, it looks like `??` is used for identifiers (table names, column names), whereas `?` is used for values (strings, numbers)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`??` is used for table and column names, it escapes them with backticks. `?` is for ordinary values.

Answer (score 4):

Barmar is right but here I am giving an example.

`??` is used for table names and column names `?` is used for normal values like parameter value in where clause.

```
let insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO ?? (??,??) VALUES (?,?)';
let query = mysql.format(insertQuery,["todo","user","notes",data.user,data.value]);
pool.query(query,(err, response) => {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    // rows added
    console.log(response.insertId);
});
```

> In the above example, first three `??` mark take table name and column
> name (`todo` is the table name and `user`, `notes` are the column name). Last two `?` take normal values those will be plain data used to be inserted into `todo` table.