# Where should ? be placed in a PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using `PreparedStatement` to select records from a table:

```
public static String getMemberInfo(String columnName, Integer memberId) {       
    String memberInfo = "";
    String sql = "SELECT ? FROM member WHERE member_id = ?";
    DatabaseConnector.setConn();

    try(Connection conn = DatabaseConnector.getConn();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        ps.setString(1, columnName);
        ps.setInt(2, memberId);

        try(ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            if(rs.next()) {
                memberInfo = rs.getString(columnName);
            }
        }

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

    return memberInfo;
}
```

When I use
`SELECT " + columnName + " FROM member WHERE member_id = ?`, it works.

But when I use 
`SELECT ? FROM member WHERE member_id = ?`, it does not.

Where should `?` be placed in prepared statements?

Comment: ? is for input values. (I.e. not selected columns.)

Comment: Related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135973/variable-column-names-using-prepared-statements

Comment: @jarlh you should probably put that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

? is for input values (typically in the `WHERE` clause conditions).

? is not for selected columns.

Answer (score 2):

Column name must be hard-coded, Only column values can be set using `?`.

but you can set dynamic column name by doing something like this :

```
String sql = "SELECT "+ columnName +" FROM member WHERE member_id = ?";
```

Comment: The restriction doesn't come from JDBC. It's the database that does not allow parameterised column names. Mostly because it cannot prepare a query plan without knowing the column and table names.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the info @Andomar I have removed that line from my answer.