# sql update with a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress plugin and I need to update some information using a variable in the query. I need a way to find the current database name and store it in a variable so that way the query works no matter what your database is named.

**UPDATE**

This is the code I'm using now. echo and print_r result in the string I want. But it's still giving me the `bind_param` error.

```
$database_name = DB_NAME;
echo "$database_name </br>";
$database_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $database_name);
print_r($database_name);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE ? . `wp_users` SET `user_pass` = ? WHERE `user_login` = ?") or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $database_name, $user_password[$i], $user_login[$i]);
```

It keeps bringing up an error that says

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

The `$current_database` variable is what's causing the error. But I thought I've syntactically done everything right. I looked up ways to do this on this site and the php docs, but none of it is working. I'm thinking I must be missing something fairly simple. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you use DB name along with table name then it should be as `dbname.tablename`

Comment: `$database_name` != `$current_database` and you're not concatenating to `wp_users` properly.

Comment: wrong identifiers used and `DB_NAME` that looks to be a constant. probably missing a concatenate also

Comment: Multiple errors here

Comment: @JohnConde I updated my code. The backticks aren't the problem. If I change them to anything else, it stops working completely.

Comment: I think @JohnConde got the call right (your question is duplicate) but he got the reason wrong. It has nothing to do with the ticks but the fact that [you can't parameterize the columns names in prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135973/variable-column-names-using-prepared-statements)

Comment: @Machavity Ah, yes, I guess this would explain my problem. One of those things no one tells you until you ask. Thanks for your help.