# Insert into with select (prepared statement)

Tags: mysql, sql

**I want this query:**

```
INSERT INTO
    users_groups (user_id, group_id)
VALUES
    (?, (SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE group_name = ?))
```

**tables:**

```
users_groups:
| user_id | group_id |

groups
| group_id | group_name |
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Embed the value as part of the select statement, you can't mix concepts of a variable and select like you tried. `(SELECT ?, group_id FROM groups WHERE group_name = ?)`

Answer (score 1):

Leave 'VALUES' out of your statement. What do you mean with the '?'; parameters? Try the script beneath. Does that serve your purpose?

```
 INSERT INTO
 users_groups (group_id)
 SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE group_name = [YOUR SELECTION]
```

Something like that (?). Or what do you mean exactly what you want to work? (PS: due to not enough rep points I can't add comments, so I have to ask the question here; I'll delete it later if answered)

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
INSERT INTO
    users_groups (user_id, group_id)
VALUES
    (SELECT ?, group_id FROM groups WHERE group_name = ?)
```

Comment: But the user_id (in your query the first ?) isn't in the groups table? Does this work anyway?

Comment: Is there any way the substitute for ? will be taken as column name?

Comment: @ed22 this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3135973/3845604) may help