# WHERE clause issue

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

Given the following SQL statement which I want to construct:

```
SELECT CONCAT(employees.first_name," ", employees.last_name), landlines.number
FROM employees,landlines WHERE employees.id=landlines.emp_id ORDER BY employees.last_name
```

initially it is created with a question mark parameter like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT(employees.first_name," ", employees.last_name), landlines.number
FROM employees,landlines WHERE employees.id=? ORDER BY employees.last_name
```

as you can see from the WHERE condition I'm referencing a field from the employees table with a field from the landlines table.  Basically a primary key field referencing a foreign key field.  Pretty standard stuff.

My problem is working with the PreparedStatement class.  I have a method that uses a switch case that looks like this:

```
PreparedStatement statement = ...;
...
//wc is a WhereCondition object and getValue() returns an Object which I cast to a particular type
Field.Type value = wc.getKey().getFieldType();
switch (value)
{
  case STRING:
      statement.setString(index, ((String)wc.getValue()));
      index++;
      break;
  case INT:
      if(wc.getValue() instanceof Field)
      {
        Field fld = (Field)wc.getValue();
        statement.setString(index,fld.toString());
      }
      else
        statement.setInt(index, ((Integer)wc.getValue()));
      index++;
      break;
  case FLOAT:
      statement.setFloat(index, ((Float)wc.getValue()));
      index++;
      break;
  case DOUBLE:
      statement.setDouble(index, ((Double)wc.getValue()));
      index++;
      break;
  case LONG:
      statement.setLong(index, ((Long)wc.getValue()));
      index++;
      break;
  case BIGDECIMAL:
      statement.setBigDecimal(index, ((BigDecimal)wc.getValue()));
      index++;
      break;
  case BOOLEAN:
      statement.setBoolean(index, ((Boolean)wc.getValue()));
      index++;
      break;
  case DATE:
      //We don't want to use the setDate(...) method as it expects
      //a java.sql.Date returned which doesn't allow for any time stamp.
      //Let the database perform the conversion from String to Date type.
      statement.setString(index, ((String)wc.getValue()));
      index++;
      break;
  case DBFUNCTION:
      statement.setString(index, ((String)wc.getValue()));
      index++;
      break;
  case IMAGE:
      statement.setString(index, ((String)wc.getValue()));
      index++;
      break;
}
```

If you look at the case INT I've tried to avoid a ClassCastException by testing for type Field and thus calling statement.setString(index,fld.toString().  The problem is that I wind up with an SQL statement with a WHERE clause that looks like this:

```
WHERE employees.id = 'landlines.emp_id'
```

Those pesky quote marks prevent the query from executing properly.  Is there a way to setXXXX the parameter for field employees.id which is of type INT so that landlines.emp_id can be entered without the quotes being added?

Comment: You can't pass an identifier (column name) as a parameter to a PreparedStatement. You need to dynamically build the SQL in Java

Comment: A `PreparedStatement` is _compiled_ at the server - therefore you must have **complete** and **valid** SQL.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135973/variable-column-names-using-prepared-statements

Comment: Looks like you don't need a `PreparedStatement` at all because you're not binding any _variables_ into the query; a plain `Statement` using the first query would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This separates the JOIN from the parameter. I can't test it in your environment so I'm not sure if it is right, but it shouldn't need the quotes:

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.first_name," ", e.last_name), l.number
FROM employees e
JOIN landlines l ON e.id=l.emp_id
WHERE e.id=? ORDER BY e.last_name
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to probably go this route and change the syntax as you suggest.  Thanks.