# SQL dynamically column name for Update with prepared statement

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an MySQL database which contains columns for ID as well as some answer possibilities for questions on client.

```
ID |    q1     |   q2     | ...
1  | answer 1  | answer 2 | ...
```

I have to adjust the entry-row dynamically, depending from the approach of the website-user (no static form).

I tried the following statement for UPDATE the database entry:

```
'UPDATE questions SET ? = ? WHERE id = ?', [data.qId, data.answer, id],
```

but it doesn´t works. when I change the first `?` to the exactly column name `q2` (and clear the array to this `?`)it works great.

Is there any possibility for this kind of dynamic column statement, because the http.request contains only the specific answer and I hope, I can solve this with an SQL statement and not with more logic in the backend.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable column names using prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135973/variable-column-names-using-prepared-statements) Short answer: You can't put column names as parameters to a prepared statement. Long Answer: This indicates bad database design. A better table would be: `ID | QuestionNumber | Answer`

Comment: @JNevill I would call this Main Problem and Bigger Problem ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I regret my choice of words. That is definitely the better way to put it.

Comment: @JNevill thank you very much for yoir answer!

Comment: Don't splay an array (answers, in this case) across columns.