# JDBC PreparedStatement with ? for Columnname won't work

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

In a university task I'm using JDBC to access a database. I wrote a finder-method that could find objects in a table by any value in any column that has integer values.

```
public ResultSet findSampleByAnyCol(String colName, Integer sampleId, Connection con) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE ? = ?"; 

    try(PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, colName);
        pstmt.setInt(2, sampleId);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();          

    }catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rs;
  }
```

I tested it and I'm sure the problem is that "?" for the colum nname doesn't work. The stack trace says "invalid number". But if I change the SQL statement to `SELECT * FROM sample WHERE sampleid = ?` it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135973/variable-column-names-using-prepared-statements), it´s not possible to do that. The "?" is just for values. To have variable columnnames it´s inevitable to do it with an own string manipulation.