# preparestatement with name

Tags: java, sql

I have a some query, but I am not sure if I should pass `'?'` in the query. Or should I treat it like a variable and just set the `"b."+ name` in the statement itself.

```
Select x,y,z
FROM someTable
WHERE ....
UNION
SELECT a.x, a.y, a.z
FROM someTable a, someTable b
WHERE a.id = ? 
AND b.seq = a.seq
AND UPPER(b.?) // is this correct???
LIKE ?
```

if I change above that line to `AND UPPER(?)`
then set statement...

```
statement.setString(x, "b."+customString);
```

or should I do this instead? `AND UPPER(b.?)`

```
statement.setString(x, customString); //or this?
```

Is the outcome the same? are there any unexpected behavior for either way?

Comment: If it's set internally, you can append it directly. If it's coming from the client... well, you have bigger problems on your hands.

Comment: table name `b` doesnt change. but i am not sure what would happen if I just append to it. or any unexpected behavior

Comment: technically correct or not it looks like a huuuuuuge backdoor gap

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3135973/217324  you can only set values as parameters, you can't specify tables or columns. this is not string interpolation.

Comment: the column name is selected based on some conditions (from the request, i am not 100% sure where the request is coming from). am i not able to set the column name from prep statement?

Comment: No, you can't use `setString` to set the column name.  You'll have to use string concatenation to get it in.  I would recommend using an enum for the available column names, so that you can avoid the situation where somebody like Bobby Tables provides an invalid column name.

Comment: but then how do you fix sql injection in this case?

Comment: The jdbc driver takes care of escaping parameter values for you. when you create a query by concatenation you have to make sure you keep user-provided data out of it. closing as a duplicate.