# MySql Prepared Statement to check particular table JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I wonder if there is a way to select table with user input in the following statement:

```
myStmt = db.myConn.prepareStatement("select * from Rooms where "
                + "idRooms = ?");
        myStmt.setInt(1, roomNum);
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery();
```

Is there a possibility to do something like `select * from =? where idRooms = ?`  to select `Rooms` with prepared statement upon user input?

```
myStmt.setString(1, Room);
mysStmt.setInt(2, roomID);
```

Thanks

Comment: No, but you can just construct the string with the user input.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: String query = "select * from " + userParamVariable + " where idRooms = ?"

Comment: This has already been answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208442/using-prepared-statements-to-set-table-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add a table name as a parameter.
You can simply create a string containing your constructed query as follows:

```
String query = "select * from " + userParamVariable + " where idRooms = ?"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you manage your tables with splitting, but unfortunately PreparedStatement does not support it, you can manually replace the table name with String.format() method.