# Returning the user details based on the search term?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```java
if (searchTerm.contains(".com") && searchTerm.contains("@")) {
    System.out.println("In email check");
    psmt.setString(1, "EMAIL_ID");
    psmt.setString(2, searchTerm);
} else if (numresult==true){
    System.out.println("In number check");
    psmt.setString(1, "MOBILE_NUMBER");
    psmt.setString(2, searchTerm);
} else if (uresult == true | alphanumeic == true) {
    System.out.println("In username check");
    psmt.setString(1, "USER_NAME");
    psmt.setString(2, searchTerm);
}

rs = psmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()) {
    HomeVo vo = new HomeVo();
    vo.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
    vo.setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
    vo.setLastName(rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
    vo.setEmailId(rs.getString("EMAIL_ID"));
    vo.setNumber(rs.getString("MOBILE_NUMBER"));
    vo.setQualification(rs.getString("QUALIFICATION"));
    vo.setState(rs.getString("STATE"));
    vo.setGender(rs.getString("GENDER"));
    vo.setUserName(rs.getString("USER_NAME"));
    vo.setDob(rs.getString("DOB"));
    return vo;
}
```

Here is my MySQL query.

```java
String FETCH_USER_BY_SEARCHTERM = "SELECT * FROM SignUpTable WHERE ? = ? ";
```

Based on the search term given by the user, this logic checks if it is a username, email or mobile number. And feeds that as the input parameter. The control goes to the particular correct if statement, but won't return any values.

Comment: I am trying to update the column name dynamically and it is taking as SELECT * FROM SignUpTable WHERE 'Email_Id' = 'searchTerm'. Any way I can make it SELECT * FROM SignUpTable WHERE Email_Id = 'searchTerm'.

Comment: it is technically possible, but I think it's bad practice. Checkout this question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1208477/1514647)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is probably some problem with the statement. You should [log the prepared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683339/1514647) statement before executing it:

```
System.out.println(psmt);
rs = psmt.executeQuery();
```

Then you should check the SQL in the MySQL console, if it returns any results. Alternatively you can check the query log. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479183/1514647) how to enable it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the error while I followed your steps.