# How Can I Assign a parameter to database table column in Springboot REST Web Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I want to assign my request and response parameters to table columns.

I am thinking of it this way ;

```
private String exParam = "SELECT exColumn" + "FROM exTable" + "WHERE exColumn2 = 'EXAMPLE'"
```

Is this the correct way or can i use sommething different, thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using Spring Boot Data JPA? Easier to write and maintain. https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Never execute raw SQL. Sanitize your input, use a prepared statement, or use the Spring Data (ORM) repository features of Spring.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I am really interested how you want to parameterize the table name with `PreparedStatement` :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/1208442/2886891

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.